# Grails relative path to controllers view folder

Tags: grails, taglib

Having a Grails 2.1 application, where I have a taglibrary for rendering a summary for different controllers, I have an issue pointing at the correct view-folder.

Eg. **TestAController** and **TestBController** both have a controller specific view file called `summary.gsp` in their respective view folders. That is `/testa/summary.gsp` and `/testb/summary.gsp`.

How can I my taglib render the `summary.gsp` that is related to the controller currently in action - I need to set a path like `"??/summary-gsp"`.

I don't want to implement any if/else logic as there could potentially be 10000 controllers using this taglib, all specifying their own `summary.gsp`.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the params object in your taglib so:

```
out << render(template: "/${params.controller}/summary")
```

Answer (score 0):

The caller should pass in the path to the template as an argument to the tag. If this argument is omitted you could use a convention for locating the template, e.g.

```
class MyTagLib {

  def renderSummary = {attrs ->

    def defaultTemplatePath = "/${params.controller}/summary"
    def templatePath = attrs.template ?: defaultTemplatePath
    out << g.render(template: templatePath)
  }
}
```